# error in c++ code SQLSTATE: 24000, Native error: 0

Tags: c++, sql

Hi I am writing c++ code to query SQL Server using `SQLExecDirect` function.It is select query.
It was working properly when I implemented
But randomly I get the below error.

```
SQLSTATE: 24000, Native error: 0, Message: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid cursor state
```

Some time query returns proper data but some time it gives above error.
How I can solve this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727907/sqlstate-24000-invalid-cursor-state

Comment: Without seeing code this could be anything.

Answer (score -1):

Please post a sample snippet and the connection options.

As a long shot, usage of MARS my resolve this.