# SQLExecDirect result -1 state 24000 in C

Tags: c++, odbc

hello there im studing C and ODBC
i got error when call SQLExecDirect function.
please help me
here is the code

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>

int main( void )
{
    //DB connect example
    SQLRETURN   nResult     = 0;
    SQLHANDLE   handleEnv   = 0;
    nResult = SQLAllocHandle( SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, ( SQLHANDLE* )&handleEnv );
    //nResult = SQLSetEnvAttr( handleEnv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, ( SQLPOINTER )SQL_OV_ODBC2, SQL_IS_INTEGER );
    nResult = SQLSetEnvAttr( handleEnv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, ( SQLPOINTER )SQL_OV_ODBC3, SQL_IS_INTEGER );
    nResult = SQLSetEnvAttr( handleEnv, SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_POOLING, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_CP_ONE_PER_HENV, SQL_IS_INTEGER);

    SQLHANDLE   handleDBC   = 0;
    nResult = SQLAllocHandle( SQL_HANDLE_DBC, handleEnv, ( SQLHANDLE* )&handleDBC );

    SQLCHAR     strConnect[ 256 ]       = "DSN=MY TEST DB; UID=TESTsa; PWD=TESTpw";
    SQLCHAR     strConnectOut[ 1024 ]   = {0};
    SQLSMALLINT nNumOut                 = 0;
    nResult = SQLDriverConnect( handleDBC, NULL, ( SQLCHAR* )strConnect, SQL_NTS, ( SQLCHAR* )strConnectOut, sizeof(strConnectOut),
                                &nNumOut, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT );

    SQLHSTMT    handleStatement = 0;
    //nResult = ::SQLAllocStmt( handleDBC, &handleStatement );
    nResult = SQLAllocHandle( SQL_HANDLE_STMT, handleDBC, ( SQLHANDLE* )&handleStatement );

    SQLHSTMT    hstmt       = handleStatement;
    int         sqlResultOutput = 0;

    SQLINTEGER  cbValue     = 0;
    nResult = SQLBindParameter( hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, SQL_C_SLONG,    SQL_INTEGER,    0, 0, &sqlResultOutput,  0, &cbValue );

    //here is the problem
    nResult = SQLExecDirect( hstmt, (SQLTCHAR*) "{CALL my_TEST_SP(?)}", SQL_NTS );
    //nResult Value is -1 and SQL State is 24000

    return 0;
}
```

every call result is fine. return SQL_SUCCESS all but one
SQLExecDirect function is return -1 and SQLState is 24000

stored procedure is simple like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_TEST_SP
 @retValue int = 0 output
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   SET @retValue = 0

   SELECT myTestCol
   FROM tTestTable

   IF @@ERROR <> 0
   BEGIN
     SET @retValue = -1
   END
END
```

my OS is windows7.
using visual studio 2010 sp1, sqlserver 2012

what i miss? please tell me and have a good day :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727907/sqlstate-24000-invalid-cursor-state

Comment: sorry i checked that but i dont understand it. but thanks your comment

Comment: Confusing, I can run this slightly modified code (connection-string, use of SQLWCHAR) just fine against sql server 2014 using 'ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server' and Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7.

Comment: my OS is windows7 64bit and ODBC driver in syswow64 is SQL server version 6.01.7601.1744 ,SQL Server Native Client 11.1 version 2011.110.2100.60 diriver in system32 folder is same both. anyway ill change code and retry by use SQLWCHAR

Comment: i change SQLCHAR to SQLWCHAR, add L to forward reteral strings and using DriverConnectW, ExecDirectW so retryed buy still SQLExecDirectW is return -1 another functions return zero(SQL_SUCCESS) i think may be its visial studio 2010 problem because i just run on that code by create new solution and project( debug mode ) but sill same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference seems to be the odbc driver version. My version is `2014.120.2000.08`. I dont think it is due to the different visual studio versions - I think they all use the same `odbc32.lib` under the hood.

The following code works for me: I changed the stored procedure to return something that is not 0 (to verify I can actually read the data returned):

```
 @retValue int = 0 output
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   SET @retValue = 3499

   SELECT myTestCol
   FROM tTestTable

   IF @@ERROR <> 0
   BEGIN
     SET @retValue = -1
   END
END
```

And I used the following code in Visual Studio 2013:

```
void printErrDbc(SQLHDBC hDbc)
{
    SQLSMALLINT recNr = 1;
    SQLRETURN ret = SQL_SUCCESS;
    while (ret == SQL_SUCCESS || ret == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
    {
        SQLWCHAR errMsg[SQL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH + 1];
        SQLWCHAR sqlState[5 + 1];
        errMsg[0] = 0;
        SQLINTEGER nativeError;
        SQLSMALLINT cb = 0;
        ret = SQLGetDiagRec(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc, recNr, sqlState, &nativeError, errMsg, SQL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH + 1, &cb);
        if (ret == SQL_SUCCESS || ret == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
        {
            std::wcerr << L"ERROR; native: " << nativeError << L"; state: " << sqlState << L"; msg: " << errMsg << std::endl;
        }
        ++recNr;
    }
}

void printErrStmt(SQLHSTMT hStmt)
{
    SQLSMALLINT recNr = 1;
    SQLRETURN ret = SQL_SUCCESS;
    while (ret == SQL_SUCCESS || ret == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
    {
        SQLWCHAR errMsg[SQL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH + 1];
        SQLWCHAR sqlState[5 + 1];
        errMsg[0] = 0;
        SQLINTEGER nativeError;
        SQLSMALLINT cb = 0;
        ret = SQLGetDiagRec(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hStmt, recNr, sqlState, &nativeError, errMsg, SQL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH + 1, &cb);
        if (ret == SQL_SUCCESS || ret == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
        {
            std::wcerr << L"ERROR; native: " << nativeError << L"; state: " << sqlState << L"; msg: " << errMsg << std::endl;
        }
        ++recNr;
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //DB connect example
    SQLRETURN   nResult = 0;
    SQLHANDLE   handleEnv = 0;
    nResult = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, (SQLHANDLE*)&handleEnv);
    //nResult = SQLSetEnvAttr( handleEnv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, ( SQLPOINTER )SQL_OV_ODBC2, SQL_IS_INTEGER );
    nResult = SQLSetEnvAttr(handleEnv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, SQL_IS_INTEGER);
    nResult = SQLSetEnvAttr(handleEnv, SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_POOLING, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_CP_ONE_PER_HENV, SQL_IS_INTEGER);

    SQLHANDLE   handleDBC = 0;
    nResult = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, handleEnv, (SQLHANDLE*)&handleDBC);

    SQLWCHAR     strConnect[256] = L"DSN=test;UID=sa;PWD=MySecretPassword";
    SQLWCHAR     strConnectOut[1024] = { 0 };
    SQLSMALLINT nNumOut = 0;
    nResult = SQLDriverConnect(handleDBC, NULL, (SQLWCHAR*)strConnect, SQL_NTS, (SQLWCHAR*)strConnectOut, sizeof(strConnectOut),
        &nNumOut, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(nResult))
    {
        printErrDbc(handleDBC);
    }

    SQLHSTMT    handleStatement = 0;
    //nResult = ::SQLAllocStmt( handleDBC, &handleStatement );
    nResult = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, handleDBC, (SQLHANDLE*)&handleStatement);

    SQLHSTMT    hstmt = handleStatement;
    int         sqlResultOutput = 0;

    SQLINTEGER  cbValue = 0;
    nResult = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, SQL_C_SLONG, SQL_INTEGER, 0, 0, &sqlResultOutput, 0, &cbValue);

    //here is the problem
    nResult = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, (SQLWCHAR*)L"{CALL my_TEST_SP(?)}", SQL_NTS);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(nResult))
    {
        printErrStmt(hstmt);
    }
    nResult = SQLMoreResults(hstmt);
    if (!(SQL_SUCCEEDED(nResult) || nResult == SQL_NO_DATA))
    {
        printErrStmt(hstmt);
    }
    std::wcout << L"Value of sqlResultOutput is: " << sqlResultOutput << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In the ODBC Data Source Administrator I created a corresponding DSN named `test` using `ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server` with version **2014.120.2000.08**. At the end the DSN entry shows the following properties (in the dialog where you can hit `Test Data Source...`):

```
Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server Version 12.00.2000

Data Source Name: test
Data Source Description: 
Server: .\SQLSERVERINSTANCE
Use Integrated Security: Yes
Database: Test
Language: (Default)
Data Encryption: No
Trust Server Certificate: No
Multiple Active Result Sets(MARS): No
Mirror Server: 
Translate Character Data: Yes
Log Long Running Queries: No
Log Driver Statistics: No
Use Regional Settings: No
Use ANSI Quoted Identifiers: Yes
Use ANSI Null, Paddings and Warnings: Yes
```

If I run this sample app I get the expected output:

```
Value of sqlResultOutput is: 3499
```

So I would suggest that you try with the latest ODBC Driver for SQL Server. I think it is this download here: http://www.microsoft.com/de-ch/download/details.aspx?id=36434

Comment: thank you for answer i just download msodbcsql.msi and install it by link but ODBC driver version is not changed strange its still start 2011 not 2014 even i uninstall ODBC driver and reuse msodbcsql.msi file ill keep try setup odbc driver version 2014

Comment: i cannot find 2014 version odbc driver. only i can find 2011 dont know why. may be i need VS2013 or SQLserver2014 so sad. but thank you for your answer erg

Comment: Yes, you could try with Sql Server 2014. I have been using SQL Server 2014 Express Edition for my test (can be downloaded for free from microsoft). Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: today i setup SQL ServerManagement 2014 ExpressEdition to runing problem code PC (not database PC)     and check "ODBC driver 11 for SQL Server 2014.120.2000.08" is installed.     so i did retry again. but i got still same result. only SQLExecDirect function return -1     maybe i need DBMS pc's ODBC driver update but its shared pc, not only i use.   therefore, i was didn't try it    and...thanks erg :) have a good day