# Invalid Cursor State Error C# DB2

Tags: c#, ado.net, db2

I run a standard query against a DB2 database with C# ADO.NET OleDb and using statements and get 
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005):  CLI0115E  Invalid cursor state. SQLSTATE=24000
When I include the dispose methods for each OleDb object, the query runs. 
Why does this fail without the Dispose methods? From everything i have researched the using statements should dispose of the objects for me. I am using .NET 4.5.1

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = DBConn.BIPSConn)
{
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
    {
        using (OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
               string orderNumber = rdr.GetString(0).Trim();
               string originCode = rdr.GetString(1).Trim();
               string destinationCode = rdr.GetString(3).Trim();

               Record record = new Record(orderNumber, originCode, destinationCode);
               RecordList.Add(record);                                             
           }
           // for unknown reasons, without these dispose methods we get an Invalid Cursor State error
           rdr.Dispose();
        }
        cmd.Dispose();
    } 
    conn.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727907/sqlstate-24000-invalid-cursor-state

Comment: try using only one GetString() and then parsing it out for your order number, originCode, and destinationCode.

Comment: @AGrammerPro how would I use only 1 GetString? The reader GetString method takes only 1 int for a specific column ordinal.

Comment: I thought that the parameters were optional. And not specifying an int would return all of your data? I could be very wrong. Sorry

Comment: This is all about `RecordList.Add(record);` -- what exactly is that doing?  If it makes a call to the DB then you know.

Comment: @AGrammerPro-- why would parsing the single record matter?

Comment: @Hogan RecordList is simply a List<Record>. The list has no interaction with a database or any other external systems. I am storing all the records in the list to later on do data manipulation. Sorry I should have included the definition in the code sample.

Comment: OK then that is not the problem -- see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a using block -- you don't want to call Dispose() you want to call Close().  The using block will take care of the dispose.  Add in a call to Close instead.

Comment: The code works with the Dispose() methods. The problem is it does not work without the Dispose() methods even though the using statement should dispose of the objects. I believe Dispose() internally calls Close() so I should not need to call Close() either.